# Image source 404 HTML

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I continue trying to display an image in my website. I have the image in the same folder as the html code trying to access it. My code is

> `<img src=”7ft.jpg” alt="not working" style=”float: right;" />`

The alt keeps popping up and the error message I get from inspect element is

> http://illuminerdi.net/school/ela/%E2%80%9Dhttp://illuminerdi.net/school/ela/7ft.jpg%E2%80%9D 404 (Not Found)

If anyone could help this would be great! (I know that this is probably obvious but I haven't used HTML for a while and nothing covers this that I can find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man! you are using the wrong " character, replace

```
<img src=”7ft.jpg” alt="not working" style=”float: right;" />
```

with this

```
<img src="7ft.jpg" alt="not working" style="float: right;" />
```

Comment: I need to figure out what caused that like now. I used the normal one as far as I am aware, but it is different. Thank you! Time to figure out what happened!
- EDIT
Figured it out! For some reason my school's keyboards use curly quotes by default!